Flutter OTP View Problem Automatic closed the keyboard and unfocused after fill one field
In this page you seen after fill one otp field keyboard automatic closed and unfocused on otpview at second field how to resolve this 
Pinput(
length: 4,
controller: _otpController,
autofocus: true,
            closeKeyboardWhenCompleted: false, // Keep keyboard open
            defaultPinTheme: PinTheme(
              width: 55,
              height: 55,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey.shade200,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            focusNode: _focusNodes[0],
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            showCursor: true,
            onChanged: (String pin) {
              setState(() {
                _isOtpComplete = pin.length == 4;
              });
            },
            onCompleted: _handlePinCompleted,
            focusedPinTheme: PinTheme(
              width: 55,
              height: 55,
              textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 26,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                border: Border.all(color: AppColors.appColor_purple, width: 2),
              ),
            ),
          ),


import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: OtpScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class OtpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _OtpScreenState createState() => _OtpScreenState();
}

class _OtpScreenState extends State<OtpScreen> {
  List<FocusNode> _focusNodes;
  List<TextEditingController> _controllers;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNodes = List.generate(4, (index) => FocusNode());
    _controllers = List.generate(4, (index) => TextEditingController());
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _focusNodes.forEach((node) => node.dispose());
    _controllers.forEach((controller) => controller.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _nextField(String value, int index) {
    if (value.length == 1) {
      if (index < _focusNodes.length - 1) {
        _focusNodes[index + 1].requestFocus();
      } else {
        _focusNodes[index].unfocus();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("OTP Verification")),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "Enter the OTP",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: List.generate(4, (index) {
                return SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: _focusNodes[index],
                    controller: _controllers[index],
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    maxLength: 1,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    onChanged: (value) => _nextField(value, index),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      counterText: "",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Implement your logic here
              },
              child: Text("Confirm OTP"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

